# Getting error in my react native authentication firebase project

Tags: firebase, react-native, authentication

Hey this is Saksham and in my project (https://github.com/Sakshamz4554/react-login-signup) i am getting an error that when i import the firebase.js file in my app.js

Uncaught error
Firebase: No Firebase App '[DEFAULT]' has been created - call Firebase App.initializeApp()

Answer (score 0):

After initializing Firebase, you need to export it.

```js
// Import the functions you need from the SDKs you need
// import * as firebase from "@firebase/app";
import firebase from '@firebase/app'
// TODO: Add SDKs for Firebase products that you want to use
// https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/setup#available-libraries

// Your web app's Firebase configuration
const firebaseConfig = {
  apiKey: "*********fgjD73UKuD3Jv9IEDgkxkW7isZM",
  authDomain: "******.firebaseapp.com",
  projectId: "fir-auth-******",
  storageBucket: "fir-auth-******.appspot.com",
  messagingSenderId: "4519537******6",
  appId: "1:451953714466:web:******bcf5f7fed317b"
};

// Initialize Firebase
let app;
if (firebase.apps.lenght === 0) {
    app = firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
} else {
    app = firebase.app()
}

const auth = firebase.auth()

export  { auth };


export default firebase
```

Later in your main app file, on top of your to be executed early when app launched.
--- App.js ---

```js
import "./firebase"
```

Comment: No i am getting error again and again but when i import firebase to my main file i always receive error  that says Uncaught error Firebase: No Firebase App '[DEFAULT]' has been created - call Firebase App.initializeApp() and when i do not import firebase then my app works fine . so can you please study my whole project and please guide me at my authentication project

Comment: Can you this snack. https://snack.expo.dev/@expofire/infinity-scroll-with-firebase

I setup Firebase there you can take reference

Comment: Can you this snack. https://snack.expo.dev/@expofire/infinity-scroll-with-firebase

I setup Firebase there you can take reference

Comment: sir no i receive error again and again and can you pls build a authentication project using react native, expo and firebase becoz i am newbie at this technology

Comment: Thank you sir for guiding me as i don't have any mentor at my efforts now i am confident having you by the way i am saksham 12 years old